# http2Server HandleStreams failure

Tags: grpc-go

I have a bidirectional streaming RPC and on the server side I see following failure message

http2Server.HandleStreams failed to read frame: read tcp4 192.168.122.155:57400->192.168.122.1:16150: read: connection reset by peer

Both Client and Server are written in golang.

I am trying to gracefully close the stream from the client side by calling stream.CloseSend() API.